# How to make pivot table having more than one column

Tags: r

I want to create a pivot table using R having more than one column. Image of My data.csv file and the desired result I want is as follows:

This is my sample data file.

[image: my data.csv]

The output what I want using R is:

[image: Desired Result using R]

The desired result can be easily obtained using pivot tables in excel but I want to use only R.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share reproducible data with `dput`

Answer (score 1):

Three steps to do using base R , no package

data:

```
    structure(list(`Registration Number` = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("123", "456"), class = "factor"), Name = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("a", "b"), class = "factor"), 
    Marks1 = c(20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70), Marks2 = c(10, 20, 30, 
    40, 50, 60)), .Names = c("Registration Number", "Name", "Marks1", 
"Marks2"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Lets use the `aggregate` function

Step 1 - Calculate sum of Marks 1 by Registration Number

```
data1<-aggregate(Marks1 ~ `Registration Number`,dataf, sum)
```

Step 2 - Calculate sum of Marks 2 by Registration Number

```
data2<-aggregate(Marks1 ~ `Registration Number`,dataf, sum)
```

Step 3 - Merge the two together

```
dataset<-merge(data1,data2)


  Registration Number Marks1 Marks2
1                 123    130    100
2                 456    140    110
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dplyr package

```
library(dplyr)
my_data %>%
group_by(rgistration_number,name)%>%
summarize(TotalMarks1=sum(marks1), TotalMarks2=sum(marks2))
```